# How to Calculate the Case of $t=0$ in the $t$-$V$ Model?

Tags: fourier-transform, fermions, ground-state, bose-hubbard-model

In the $t$-$V$ model, the Hamiltonian is defined as:

\begin{equation}
\hat H = -t \displaystyle \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} ( \hat c_i^{\dagger} \hat c_j + \hat c_j^{\dagger} \hat c_i) + V \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \hat n_i \hat n_j.
\end{equation}

Here, $t$ denotes the electron hopping parameter, and $V$ represents the nearest neighbor Coulomb interaction strength.

Case for $V=0$: I'm aware that for $V=0$, the $t$-$V$ model simplifies to a non-interacting system, which can be solved by transforming to Fourier space and diagonalizing a quadratic matrix.

Case for $t=0$ : Conversely, how could one approach solving the $t=0$ case? This scenario represents a limit where electron hopping is forbidden. How would one analyze the behavior of the system under these conditions, particularly in a 2D square lattice?

Any insights or mathematical methodologies for these extreme cases in the context of a 2D square lattice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's easy to diagonalize this Hamiltonian for $t=0$: the eigenstates are just the Fock states populating the sites, and the energy is just going to count the number of pair-wise interactions between neighboring sites. For example, the state $\hat{c}^{\dagger}_1\hat{c}^{\dagger}_2|0\rangle$ (1 particle each on sites 1 and 2) will have en energy $V$. To my mind, that it makes the behavior likely pretty uninteresting.

Comment: thank you for the comment. So in Fourier space we would get $\displaystyle H_V(k) = V \sum_{kq} n_k n_{q}$ (after replacing the operators)? and we would simply check for the nearest neighbours and sum the V contributions?

Comment: If by Fourier space you mean writing the operators in terms of the ones that diagonalize the $t$-term, then no; the $V$ term can*not* be written that way: it's not diagonal in Fourier space because it's diagonal in *position* space (or what amounts to position space, which is the site-basis) I recommend acting with the $V$-term on states like the one I wrote down in my previous comment *directly* to see how this works.