# Fourier transform of spinless $t$-$V$ model for $t=0$

Tags: energy, hamiltonian, fourier-transform, fermions, bose-hubbard-model

I am trying to compute the Fourier transform of the 2D $t$-$V$  model for the case $t=0$.

\begin{equation}
\hat H = -t \displaystyle \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} ( \hat c_i^{\dagger} \hat c_j + \hat c_j^{\dagger} \hat c_i) + V \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \hat n_i \hat n_j.
\end{equation}

My attempt:

To compute the Fourier transform of the $t-V$ model for the case where $t = 0$, we start by expressing the Hamiltonian in momentum space. Given that the hopping term $t$ vanishes, we only need to consider the potential term:

$\hat{H} = V \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \hat{n}_i \hat{n}_j$

Let's express this in terms of creation and annihilation operators in momentum space. The Fourier transform of the electron annihilation operator $\hat{c}_i$ is given by:

$
\hat{c}_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k e^{-ikr_i} \hat{c}_k
$

where $N$ is the total number of lattice sites, $k$ is the wavevector, and $r_i$ is the position of lattice site $i$.

Therefore, the electron number operator $\hat{n}_i$ can be expressed as:

$
\hat{n}_i = \hat{c}_i^\dagger \hat{c}_i = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k,k'} e^{i(k'-k)r_i} \hat{c}_{k'}^\dagger \hat{c}_k
$

Hence, the Hamiltonian in momentum space becomes:

$
\hat{H} = \frac{V}{N^2} \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \sum_{k,k'} e^{i(k'-k)(r_j-r_i)} \hat{c}_{k'}^\dagger \hat{c}_k \hat{c}_{k}^\dagger \hat{c}_{k'}$

I wonder if we can further simplify, is my attempt correct? Is it possible to compute the energy eigenvalues like in the case of V=0 where the solution corresponds $e_k = -2t(cos(kx)+cos(ky))$.

Comment: This really seems like the same question as your [previous one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/806171/how-to-calculate-the-case-of-t-0-in-the-t-v-model). *Why* do you want to compute the Fourier transform of $\hat{H}$ for $t=0$? It doesn't get you anything, because $\hat{H}$ is *already diagonal* when it's written in the form $V \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \hat n_i \hat n_j$. And did you take my recommendations in the comments to the other post to heart?  Did you see how, for instance, $\hat{c}_1^{\dagger}\hat{c}_2^{\dagger}|0\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$ when $t=0$?

Comment: yes, thank you. I understand that $\hat H$ is already diagonal in real space and that we can compute the energies from here. I would like to go to fourier space, because what happens if one wants to compute the lowest energies of different total momentum ($K=\sum_i k_i$) sectors? 
for instance, in the case $V=0$: the eigenvalue energy will differ for different $K$ configurations ($e_k = -2t(cos(kx)+cos(ky))$ depends on the $k$ values of the particles)

Comment: All right, I see, so you really are looking for the eigenvalues of the entire Hamiltonian, and seeing if moving to Fourier space will help you with that.  AFAIK, there is no *analytic* expression for the energies and eigenvectors of even the simplest (1D) Bose-Hubbard model. You could construct the matrix of the Hamiltonian in a constant-number eigenbasis (if the number is small enough), and diagonalize that, but it's likely better to do it in position space than in Fourier space. Otherwise, you can make mean-field approximations, etc.

Comment: okay! thank you again for your help. very much appreciated